# exclude a property in NSFetchRequest

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I need to fetch an entity with all properties expect one property. I know that there is way to include name of all properties to do such a thing:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

[request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
[request setPropertiesToFetch:
 [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"property1", @"property2", /* etc. */ nil]];

NSEntityDescription *e = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName
                                     inManagedObjectContext:self.context];
```

But I don't want to mention all of properties because of one property!
Do you know any good performance solution for this?

Comment: Why do you want to exclude one property?  If it's a memory-optimisation, to avoid loading a big property such as an image, you could instead have a separate entity for that property, with a 1:1 relationship to your existing entity.  You can then fetch your existing entity without memory worries, and only fetch the related entity if required.

Comment: Exactly pbasfd! I have blob images and it cause high memory usage.In addition, It seems that setPropertiesToFetch does not work and memory usage is same as previous when scrolling all the uitableview.

Comment: @pbasdf - You have the right answer.  Unfortunately, the OP asked the wrong question ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you're going to have to name all properties except the one. There is no other way. Here is a way to do it automatically and don't worry about performance.

```
NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:self.context];
NSArray *allProperties = entityDescription.properties;
NSMutableArray *propertiesToFetch = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:allProperties.count];
for (NSPropertyDescription *property in allProperties) {
    if (![property.name isEqualToString:@"xxx"]) {
        [propertiesToFetch addObject:property];
    }
}

NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:entityName];
request.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;
request.propertiesToFetch = propertiesToFetch;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this approach to remove a particular property from an array of all the properties. Let's assume your Entity is called `PatientRecord`.

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

[request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];

PatientRecord *patient;
NSMutableArray *allProperties = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:patient.entity.properties];
[allProperties removeObject:@"propertyToRemove"];

[request setPropertiesToFetch:allProperties];

NSEntityDescription *e = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName
                                 inManagedObjectContext:self.context];
```

Comment: Not going to work, check the doc about the `properties` attribute of `NSEntityDescription`

Comment: Please explain the reason why it won't work? I have used this before (in more that one way). What exactly should i look for in the docs?

Comment: The `properties` array doesn't contain strings but `NSPropertyDescription` subclasses. See my answer.

Comment: Your solution 'works' because it doesn't remove anything from the array and fetches everything (which works...)